# Google Docs API - Edit Text as Suggestion

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

The Google Docs API mentions [how to get a document with suggestion](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/suggestions) (track changes), but it says nothing about how to add a suggestion to a document.

How would you insert an edit suggestion in a document using the Google Docs API or Apps Script ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately it isn't currently possible to make suggestions to a Google Doc via the API.*

#### More Information:

As you've pointed out already, it is currently only possible to [view suggested edits](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/suggestions) but not create them. Aside from the lack of endpoint for them, you can see in the [Batch Update](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) and [request](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request) documentation pages, that there are no entries for suggestions either.

#### Feature Request:

If you really want this to be added to the Docs API (and therefore subsequently in Apps Script) however, you can head over to Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and submit a Feature Request asking for this to be implemented.

#### References:

- [Working with suggestions](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/suggestions)
- [Method: `documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [Requests](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request)
- [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Did somebody open an issue for this? I would also love to see this working via the API :-) Would be really cool!

Comment: I would also love to see this